# Where's the neutral bus bar in this picture?

Tags: electrical-panel

Sorry about the newbie question here but just want to learn this the right way. Is the neutral bus bar the one with the white wires (on the right) or the one with the copper and green wire (on the left)? If it's the one on the right then what's the one on the left called and what is it for?

Thanks!

[image: panel]

Comment: this looks like a subpanel to me for 3 reasons; 1) neutral wire in the feeder 2) no main breaker and most importantly 3) the neutral and ground bars are not connected.

Answer (score 3):

There's a neutral bar on each side of the panel, which are bonded using the large strap across the top of the panel. Then  there's a grounding bar down on the left side.

[image]

Comment: The green screw that connects the crossover bar to the neutral bar on the right, likely passes all the way through to the enclosure. However, it looks like the panel is fed by a 4-wire feeder, which suggests to me that the neutral may be bonded elsewhere. If the neutral is bonded before this panel, that screw may have to be replaced with a shorter, non-green screw.

Comment: So @Tester101 are you suggesting that this is a subpanel and so the ground and neutral should not be bonded there? Could this be the main panel and the heavy stranded aluminum ground be going to grounding rods?

Comment: @JimStewart No, I'm just pointing out that the neutral bonding *may* be before this panel. And suggesting that if that's the case, the OP *may* have to remove the screw that's connecting neutral to ground in this panel. The neutral being bonded before the panel does not necessarily make a panel a "sub panel". The bonding can legally occur at the service connection, the meter, or the disconnect.  Bonding the neutral at the meter, would not make this a "sub panel", for example.